# Why does the object get duplicated multiple times?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, object, generics

I want to know understand the way the object creation/referencing is happening. I have a piece of code where all Employee objects in my list are duplicated. The top code has the issue that overrides all previous entries so the list contains duplicated objects whereas the bottom was my fix. I want to understand why creating the new object inside the while.Read() loop worked whereas having the employee object creation outside of the while loop did not.

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees
{
    get
    {
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            Employee _employee = new Employee(); //<issue is here, all enties in employees are duplicated values of a single record
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("spGetAllEmployees", connection);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                _employee.EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["EmployeeID"]); //object instantiation here fixed the issue, why?
                _employee.Name = (reader["Name"].ToString());
                _employee.Gender = (reader["Gender"].ToString());
                _employee.City = (reader["City"].ToString());
                _employee.DateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateOfBirth"]);
                _employee.DepartmentID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["DepartmentID"]);
                employees.Add(_employee);
            }
        }
        return employees;
    }
}
```

I want to understand why this fixed the issue.

```
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees
            {
                get
                {
                    List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

                    using (SqlConnection connection = new 

SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("spGetAllEmployees", connection);
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Employee _employee = new Employee(); //this fixed the issue, why?
                        _employee.EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["EmployeeID"]);
                        _employee.Name = (reader["Name"].ToString());
                        _employee.Gender = (reader["Gender"].ToString());
                        _employee.City = (reader["City"].ToString());
                        _employee.DateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateOfBirth"]);
                        _employee.DepartmentID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["DepartmentID"]);
                        employees.Add(_employee);
                    }
                    }
                    return employees;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, you have a single `_employee` object, created outside the loop.  This object is stored in a single reference in memory.  When you use `Add(_employee)`, you are not creating a new object with the current properties of the `_employee`, you are adding the reference to that single object in memory to the list, multiple times.  When you change the value of any of the properties of `_employee` on subsequent trips through the loop, you are changing that single object in memory, which is, in effect, changing every item in the list.

In the second example, you are creating a new `_employee` object every loop through the `while`, and each new object has a new memory address.  Therefore, every object you add in to the list is independent of the last.

Answer (score 0):

Typeof `Employee` is a Reference Type which is just a pointer to another memory location that holds the real data.

In the first example you are only initializing one instance of `Employee` (a reference type). In the `while` loop you keep adding that same instance to the collection, and at the same time update its properties (all the items in the collection will have their properties set the the values of the last row in the database).

In the second example you create a new instance in each iteration and set its properties based on the current row. The next iteration creates another instance and sets its properties.

[This article](http://net-informations.com/faq/general/valuetype-referencetype.htm) might help explain the difference between a reference type and a value type.